# VERBOSE environment in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a Bash script, which compiles and runs all C files in the current directory. My Bash script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST="$(ls *.c)"
echo "Compile all C source files"

for f in $( ls *.c); do
    #echo "C file: $f"
    gcc $f -o "${f%.*}"
    ./"${f%.*}"

done
```

Now, I'm trying to define a `VERBOSE` environment variable. If `VERBOSE` environment variable is set then my Bash script should display the command that is being used to compile the source file.

How can I define such a `VERBOSE` environment variable in this Bash script?

When verbose is defined my output should be like,

```
    Compiling all C source files:
    gcc copyfile.c -o copyfile
    ---- successful ----
    gcc haserror.c -o haserror
    haserror.c: In function ‘main’:
    haserror.c:9:10: warning: missing terminating " character
    printf("Hello !\n);
    ^
    haserror.c:9:10: error: missing terminating " character
    printf("Hello!\n);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    haserror.c:11:1: error: expected expression before ‘}’ token
    }
    ^
    haserror.c:11:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
    gcc hello.c -o hello
    ---- successful ----
    gcc p005.c -o p002
    ---- successful ----
    gcc p103.c -o p101
    ---- successful ----
    gcc p102.c -o p105
    ---- successful ----
    ============
    5 C source files are compiled successfully.
    1 C source files have compilation error(s).

**Otherwise, when my VERBOSE not defined, my output should be like**

Compiling all C source files:
haserror.c: In function ‘main’:
haserror.c:9:10: warning: missing terminating " character
printf("Hello!\n);
^
haserror.c:9:10: error: missing terminating " character
printf("Hello!\n);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
haserror.c:11:1: error: expected expression before ‘}’ token
}
^
haserror.c:11:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
============
5 C source files are compiled successfully.
1 C source files have compilation error(s).
```

Comment: I would solve this problem through a `Makefile` with `make`, which already has a "VERBOSE" mode and a dry-run mode too. For GNU `make`, the Makefile is basically: `SRC=$(wildcard *.c)

test: $(SRC)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)`

Comment: `( if [ "${VERBOSE:-}" = true ]; then set -x; fi; gcc ... ; );`

Comment: @KamilCuk I was just about to post that. Except I’d just check for non-empty, rather than `true`.

Comment: (OT: [`for f in $( ls *.c)` should be `for f in *.c`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs))

Comment: @kamilCukt where should I add  your solution to my code, can you add a code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivially obvious shoud work.

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$VERBOSE" ] && echo "$0: Compile all C source files" >&2

for f in *.c; do
    [ "$VERBOSE" ] && echo "$0: C file: $f" >&2
    # [ "$VERBOSE" ] && set -x
    gcc $f -o "${f%.*}"
    # set +x
    ./"${f%.*}"
done
```

Notice also how we avoid the [useless (and slightly dangerous) use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls) and print the diagnostic output to standard error, with the script's name included in the message.

The condition is simple; `[ "$VERBOSE" ]` evaluates to true (returns a zero exit code) when `VERBOSE` is set and non-empty. You can perform arbitrarily complex actions conditionally using the shell's normal flow control statements, such as perhaps

```
if [ "$VERBOSE" ]; then
    echo "$0: compiling $f" >&2
    (set -x; gcc "$f" -o "${f.c}") &&
    echo "$0: ----- $f: successful -----" >&2
else
    gcc "$f" -o "${f.c}"
fi
```

(though I would perhaps then also refactor the compilation command into a separate function.)

A better design is to have the script accept a command-line option. Also, you should probably avoid using upper case for your private variables.

Comment: You might want to wrap `set -x` and the `gcc` line in some brackets, so as not to start printing other commands as well.

Comment: The requirements are pretty murky, but feel free to edit this if you feel confident that you understand precisely what the OP wants.

Comment: @tripleee requirements are, when VERBOSE environment is defined, then my bash shell script should display the command that is being used to compile the source file. And when also I should display the VERBOSE environment is not defined. Purpose of this work is understanding environment variables.

Comment: The beef here is that `[ "$VERBOSE" ]` is true when `VERBOSE` is set and non-empty. You can `echo` something or enable `set -x` or do many other things when this is true.

Comment: I added sample outputs, can you check? @tripleee

Comment: I added some examples, but I have not attempted to implement the counting of successes and failures, which wasn't part of your original question. You can figure out that part yourself.